# Access local variable inside d3 anonymous function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, anonymous-function

I am working with d3 and javascript and I am new to them. I am trying to pass a variable inside anonymous function for click but I cant get it to work.Here is an example:

```
var someVariable=xyz;
var mapModel=someObj;


svg.append("g")
    .style("display","table")
    .style("margin","0 auto")
    .data(topojson.feature(mapModel, mapModel.objects[objdisplay]).features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
    .attr("d", this.path)
    .on("click",function(d){
            alert(someVariable + d.id)
    });
```

I need to access `somevariable` inside anonymous function for click but can't seem to get it working.This question might have been asked before but can someone help me in going in the right direction.Thanks

Comment: This looks valid. Variables declared outside the function scope are accessible by everything inside the function scope.

Comment: @Ixe I am sorry but it is not accessible there.In the developer console, it gives not available error.I am only able to access `d`

Comment: try this in your console to demonstrate it as a generic case:

`var someVariable='hello';
setTimeout(function () {
  alert(someVariable + ' world');
}, 1000);`

Comment: The syntax looks off here. Is `svg` a selection you renamed to a variable? Why are you using `.enter()`? (A little context would help answer better). Regardless, you will have access to to variable `someVariable`. I tried it out in my own console to make sure it wasn't something weird with D3, and it works for me. If you don't have access to it there must be something else going on. What you should not have access to is whatever `d` is. Can you explain what that is? Perhaps that is where you are getting the error.

Comment: I am trying to build a world map based on the topojson data I recieved.`svg` is just my parent svg on which I am building the map.Everything works fine. Just that on a particular country click, I want to access a variable which is defined in the parent scope which I am not able to get.

Comment: I have edited my example to give a better idea about what I am doing. Please have a look.

Comment: can you set up a fiddle with your problem

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are there errors in the console? Does the alert show up? If it does, what is its output? What does your definition of `this.path` look like? As you can see from the comments and answers, there are many people around willing to help, but you need to provide more information about your problem and its context. As others have mentioned, setting up a live demo ([mcve]) would be very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You can't access 'someVariable' inside your click function this way . 
Try this...

```
var someVariable=xyz;
svg.append("g")
    .style("display","table")
    .style("margin","0 auto")
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .data([{'someVariable':someVariable}])
   .on("click",function(d){
            alert(d.someVariable + d.id)
    });
```

Comment: Why downvote ? May I know the reason ? Am I doing anything wrong ?